# Are there any trends for electrical conductivity?

Tags: periodic-trends, conductivity

> Which element has the greatest electrical conductivity?
>   *(A)* $\ce{As}$
>   *(B)* $\ce{Ge}$ 
>   *(C)* $\ce{P}$ 
>   *(D)* $\ce{Sn}$

I am unsure of how to approach this problem. Is there some sort of trend for electrical conductivity or some other method to determine which of these answers the question?

I am pretty sure it is not $\ce{Ge}$ as that is used for semi-conductors, and am pretty sure it is not $\ce{P}$ because that is a non-metal but I don't know how to narrow down between the others.

Comment: Phosphorus allotropes are white, red, and black.  Arsenic allotropes are gray, yellow, and black.  Germanium allotropes are alpha- and beta-.  Tin allotropes are white and gray (Napoleon learned about that outside Moscow).  Have some fun with the question, doi:10.1063/1.1729699

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am unsure of how to approach this problem.

No, you are not! You have already reduced the number of candidates by good reasoning!

At this point, one

- *could* have a look at conductivity tables or remember in which period the metal blocks start for every main group or
- **remember typical electricity-related uses of $\ce{As}$ and $\ce{Sn}$**

Did you ever form a conducting connection between electronic components (or just some wires) by *soldering*? $\Leftarrow$

(Do you recall that $\ce{GaAs}$ is used as a semiconductor material in thin film solar cells?)